# Simple groups of order 300

Tags: group-theory

I am aware of [No simple group of order $300$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13111/no-simple-group-of-order-300).
It is said that "there would be 6 Sylow 5-groups, one of which will have an index of 6", but why does one have index 6? If we write $|G|=p^k m$ where $p\nmid m$, then by Lagrange's theorem any $p$-Sylowgroup has index $m$, which in this case is 12?

Comment: Indeed, that is an error (note that it does not appear in the accepted answer).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you said is said in that link is a serious blunder: as all the Sylow $\,5-$subgroups *obviously* have the same order then they all have the same index.

What is true is that the number of different Sylow $\,5-$subgroups equals the index of the normalizer of any of them, so we have a subgroup $\,N\le G\,$ with $\,[G:N]=6\;$. 
This already leads to a contradiction if we suppose $\,G\;$  is simple, as then the regular action of $\,G\,$ on $\,N\,$ gives us an injective homomorphism $\,G\to S_6\,$...but this is impossible (why?) .

Comment: Since in this case $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_6$, but the order of $G$ does not divide the order of $S_6$. Thanks for clarification!