# Show that $|G|=1000$ is not simple

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory, simple-groups

I think I've done this, but I just want to check it's proved **enough**.

So $|G|=1000=8\cdot125$.

Then $n_5\in\{\text{factors of 8}\}$ so $n_5\in\{1,2,4,8\}$ congruent to $1\bmod5$.

$2$, $4$, $8$ are not congruent to $1\bmod5$.

So $n_5=1$ and if $n_p=1$ then the Sylow $p$-subgroup is unique and normal so $G$ cannot be simple.

Comment: Yes, and for the general idea see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13111/no-simple-group-of-order-300?rq=1.

Comment: Everything is fine, you could add the proof verification tag :-)

Answer (score 0):

In general, we know that every group whose order is divisible by exactly two primes is not only non-simple, but also solvable.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning the name of the result, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_theorem

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that.